# JUnit: expected<java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException> but was<java.lang.NullPointerException>

Tags: java, junit, nullpointerexception, singly-linked-list

I have a linked list program that mimics the String and StringBuilder classes- the program compiles and runs fine, the problem is arises when testing it in JUnit.

Failures: 
1) t33bTestIndexOutOfBoundsCharAtLength0
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected but was

2) t34bTestIndexOutOfBoundsSetCharAtLength0
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected but was
        ... 2 more

So I'm not sure where the NullPointerException is coming from.

Here's my code:

```
//Relevant Junit tests    

  @Test(expected=IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
  public void t33bTestIndexOutOfBoundsCharAtLength() {
     LString testLString = new LString(testString);
     System.out.println(testString.length());
     testLString.charAt(testString.length());
  } 

  @Test(expected=IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
  public void t34bTestIndexOutOfBoundsSetCharAtLength() {
     LString testLString = new LString(testString);
     testLString.setCharAt(testString.length(), newChar);
  }
```

More

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;``


public class LString{

    /*--------------------------- node class ------------------------*/   
   public class node{
              public char c;
              public node next;   

              /*---   node constructors   ---*/      
              public node(){
              }//end

              public node( char ch){
                 c = ch; 
             next = null;        
              }//end             

           public node(char dt, node obj){
               c = dt;
               next = obj.next;
           }//end    

           public String toString(){
               return c + "";
           } //end 


           public void setChar(char ch){
               this.c=ch;
           }

           public char getChar(){
               return this.c;
           }

   }
    /*----------------------- end node class ------------------------*/         

/*------  fields  --------*/
   private node front = null;
   private int counter=0;

/*---- constructors  -----*/
   public LString (){                       
   }//end 


   public LString(String str){      

      for(int i =0; i < str.length(); i++){   this.append(str.charAt(i));   }
   }//end


/*-------  methods -------*/

   public int length(){
         return counter;
   }//end length


   public boolean inBounds( int index){
      if( index < 0 || index > counter) return false;
      else return true;
   }//end inBounds    


   private void append(char ch){
          if (front == null) {  front = new node(ch);  }//nothing follows
         else { 
               node curr = front;
               while (curr.next != null) {  curr = curr.next;    }
                curr.next = new node(ch);              
        }
       counter++;
    }//end append


   public char charAt(int idx){           
         if ( (inBounds(idx)==false) || idx< 0 ) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("");
         else{   
            if(front == null) return front.getChar();             
            node curr = this.front;
            for(int i =0; i< idx; i++){   
                  curr = curr.next;                    
            }     

            return curr.getChar();
         }         
   }//end charAt 


   public void setCharAt(int idx, char ch){
         node curr = front;

         if ( !(inBounds(idx)) || idx < 0  ) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("");
         else{     for(int i =0; i< idx; i++){   curr = curr.next;  }     

         } 

         curr.setChar(ch);                  
   }//end setCharAt    


   public String toString() {
       StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

       node curr = front;
       while ( curr != null ) {
           str.append(curr.toString() );
           curr = curr.next;
       }
       return str.toString();
   }//end toString


   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object other){
        if (other == null || !(other instanceof LString) )  return false;       
        else{
            LString nother = (LString) other;
            return (  Arrays.equals(this.toString().toCharArray(), nother.toString().toCharArray()  )  );
         }
   }//end equals


   public LString substring(int start, int end){
        if( !(inBounds(start)) || !(inBounds (end)) ) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("");
        if( start == end || this.length() ==0 ) return (new LString() );
        else{ 
            String sub = "";      
            for(int i =start; i <= (end -1); i++){  sub += String.valueOf(  this.charAt(i)  );  }

            return ( new LString(sub) );        
         }
   }//end substring


   public int compareTo(LString other){

        if(Arrays.equals( this.toString().toCharArray(),  other.toString().toCharArray() )     ) return 0;
        else if( (other.length() != this.length())    )   return (this.length() - other.length() );
        else{
            int lexic=0;

            node thisCurr = front;            
            node otherCurr = other.front;

            for(int i =0; i < this.length(); i++){
                    if( thisCurr.c != otherCurr.c) lexic += (   ( (int)thisCurr.c ) -  ( (int)otherCurr.c)   );
                    thisCurr = thisCurr.next;
                    otherCurr = otherCurr.next;
            }   
            return lexic;
        }
   }//end compareTo 


   public LString replace(int start, int end, LString lstr){

        if( !(inBounds(start))  ||  !(inBounds(end)) || end < start) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("");
        else{   
               if (start == end) return (   new  LString(this.substring(0, start) + lstr.toString() + this.substring(end, this.length() )   )   );
               if ( start == end || end == this.length() )  return (  new LString(this.toString() + lstr.toString()  )   );
               else return (   new LString( this.substring(0, start) + lstr.toString() + this.substring(end, this.length() ))   );
         }      
   }//end replace             
}
/*****************  end LString class ***************/
```

Comment: Check your stacktrace, it should tell you exactly where it happened.

Comment: Can you post your unit test code as well?

Comment: you are using this.length(). I think somewhere your this is getting set as null. check your console for stack trace. paste it here

Comment: Get rid of the expected exception bit, it makes it much easier to find the stack trace. You can put it back in once the test is behaving as expected.

Comment: Why not just to debug it and go step by step and see where the object is null?

Comment: Aside from checking the stacktrace, which clearly shows the location of your error, consider running your code through a code formatter.  You frequently have multiple statements on one line which can make the debugging difficult even when you have the line number.

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of the `testString` that you use in your 2 tests? If they are `null`, you'll get a `NullPointerException` in the `LString` constructor.